# How to trigger page refreshes on input change in blazor app

Tags: blazor

I'm starting out with razor and trying to simply refresh my page with new data when I enter data in a search textbox.

My code - Component:

```
<div class="text-lg-start bg-blue-100">
    <input class="border-4 w-1/3 rounded m-6 p-6 h-8 border-blue-300" @bind-value="SearchText" @bind-value:event="oninput" placeholder="Search by title" />
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Btn</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var movie in movies)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => Hire(movie)">Rent</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

@code {
    private Movie[]? movies;
    [Parameter]
    public string SearchText { get; set; } = "";
    async Task Hire(Movie movie)
    {
       protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
       {
           movies = await MovieService.GetMovies(SearchText);
       }
       protected override async void OnParametersSet()
       {
           movies = await MovieService.GetMovies(SearchText);
       }
   }
```

My code - Service:

```
 public class MovieService
 {
    private static readonly Movie[] MovieTest = new[]
    {
         new Movie(90, new List<string>(){"Horror"}, "The Skeleton Key"),
         new Movie(120, new List<string>(){ "Science Fiction"}, "Star Wars")
    };
    public Task<Movie[]> GetMovies(string? search = null)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(MovieTest);
    }
}
```

The only thing I want to achieve is that the screen gets refreshed based on what I put in the search box (typing 'SK' I would like to only see the skeleton key).

I found a working example where you filter the clientside data in the component, but I specifically wish to call the async service function, so that I can replace the body with an actual service call later. Anyone know what I am doing wrong or missing here?

P.S.
I tried adding `@page "/{SearchText: string}"` besides my standard `@page "/"`, but this causes a null-reference exception in the _Host.cshtml

Comment: In title you are saying that you want to refresh page when button is clicked but then you say that you want to refresh page when search input changes and then you try to pass a `DateTime` parameter to your page, can you clarify what you actually want?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Yes, you are right! I was trying multiple different things and some changed stuff got through in my question, thank you. I fixed it now. What I want is that the page refreshes and calls GetMovies function everytime when I change the input of the SearchText field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@onchange` EventCallback to call your service when the `input` element loses focus:

```
<input class="..." value="@SearchText" @onchange="HandleChange" placeholder="Search by title" />

@code {
    private Movie[]? movies;

    [Parameter]
    public string? SearchText { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        movies = await MovieService.GetMovies(SearchText);
    }

    private async Task HandleChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchText = e?.Value?.ToString();

        movies = await MovieService.GetMovies(SearchText);
    }
}
```

You can also use `@oninput` EventCallback in the same way:

```
<input class="..." value="@SearchText" @oninput="HandleChange" placeholder="Search by title" />
```

but this will trigger `MovieService.GetMovies` immediately after every input change, so you shouldn't use it if your service makes actual http calls to a backend server or queries to a database.

Use whichever fits best for you scenario.

[Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: The original question was trying to use `oninput` - `@bind-value:event="oninput"`-  so you probably want to wire HandleChange up to the `oninput` event.

Comment: [Polite] Agree if `GetMovie` is really a direct call into a database.  But the intent may be to narrow the list down as the user types in a letter from a cached list.  I only commented as the OP did specifically set the bind to `oninput`.

Comment: I edited the answer to also mention the `oninput` event. Thanks for your suggestion.